# Aws Cognito no refresh token after login

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon Cognito for authorization of my app.

I'm using the authorization code flow. I can successfully get my token on /oauth2/authorize?...

But I can't seem to successfully get access_token, id_token and refresh_token using the POST to /oauth2/token with the Content type header: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

and body:

```
{"key":"grant_type","value":"authorization_code"},
{"key":"client_id","value":"xyz"}, 
{"key":"redirect_uri","value":"redirect-url.com"}, 
{"key":"code","value":"code_from_previous_request"}
```

When I make this call I get the following error json:

```
{"error":"invalid_request"}
```

Client id is correct and client app has no secret.

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That request body isn't `x-www-form-urlencoded`; it looks very much like JSON.  Are you sending it through a tool or function that creates a proper urlencoded string?  If not, that's likely your problem.  The `POST` [body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) should be in the format `param=value&otherParam=otherValue&...`.

Comment: @MikePatrick The body I provided was just to represent which values i'm passing, I'm using postman to insert these values x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I hoped that was the case.  I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted.  Perhaps you can export the Postman request as code (HTTP or cURL) and post it?  This endpoint is picky about minor things - for example, a missing trailing slash on the `redirect_uri` produces an `unauthorized_client` error that can be quite perplexing.

Comment: @MikePatrick Thanks for the reply, I also noticed the endpoint acts pretty picky about some things... I tried exporting the request to a cURL command but it's still not working :/

Comment: My words were poorly chosen.  By "post it", I meant add it to the question, rather than `POST` it to the endpoint..  No matter, for reference, I put a lightly obfuscated HTTP sample that works for me [here](https://gist.github.com/mikepatrick/63a2b2524a47c8330cd8c86d65dd4636).  If you export your request from Postman as HTTP, and compare to this example, does anything stand out?

Comment: @MikePatrickThanks for your help, I found the solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

By taking a closer look a @MikePatrick's request I figured it out. I was sending a wrong parameter

```
redirect_url
```

instead of

```
redirect_uri
```

...

Note to self: Half of software bugs are caused by typos